# Too many threads on WAITING state in Jetty server

Tags: java, multithreading, embedded-jetty, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard and the embedded jetty server which comes with it. Recently I am noticing too many threads having WAITING state. If I look at the trend then number of threads WAITING bumps up by 5 every time. The acceptors and threadpool for the jetty servers are left at default which Dropwizard provides. Following is the threaddump of the server. Any explanation for this valid/invalid behaviour is appreciated.

```
"pool-9-thread-5" #80940 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000081b6000 nid=0x50ca waiting on condition [0x00007f6f46574000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2f98e70> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-9-thread-4" #80939 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000008589000 nid=0x50c9 waiting on condition [0x00007f6f48b8c000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2f98e70> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-9-thread-3" #80938 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000028d4000 nid=0x50c8 waiting on condition [0x00007f6f4777e000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2f98e70> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-9-thread-2" #80937 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000aa3c800 nid=0x50c7 waiting on condition [0x00007f6f4737c000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2f98e70> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-9-thread-1" #80936 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000008e1b800 nid=0x50c6 waiting on condition [0x00007f6f45f70000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2f98e70> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-8-thread-5" #80896 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000005fd0800 nid=0x4eec waiting on condition [0x00007f6f46372000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2f77570> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-8-thread-4" #80895 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000068f7000 nid=0x4eeb waiting on condition [0x00007f6f45768000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2f77570> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-8-thread-3" #80894 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000017d9000 nid=0x4eea waiting on condition [0x00007f6f46877000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2f77570> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-8-thread-2" #80893 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000001753000 nid=0x4ee9 waiting on condition [0x00007f6f4878a000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2f77570> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-8-thread-1" #80892 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000003142800 nid=0x4ee8 waiting on condition [0x00007f6f4727b000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2f77570> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-7-thread-5" #80614 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000255b800 nid=0x3e5a waiting on condition [0x00007f6f46271000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2e78360> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-7-thread-4" #80613 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000777f000 nid=0x3e59 waiting on condition [0x00007f6f46675000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2e78360> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-7-thread-3" #80612 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000001b00000 nid=0x3e58 waiting on condition [0x00007f6f45a6b000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2e78360> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-7-thread-2" #80611 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000008838800 nid=0x3e57 waiting on condition [0x00007f6f45566000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2e78360> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-7-thread-1" #80610 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000050f1000 nid=0x3e56 waiting on condition [0x00007f6f46978000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2e78360> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: looks like a lot of `ThreadPoolExecutor` are created by mistake.

Comment: The names you are seeing (eg: `"pool-7-thread-3"`) are not a naming syntax or convention that Jetty uses.  Perhaps this is a DropWizard specific configuration?  or perhaps these executors are not part of Jetty or DropWizard, but something in your application or its libraries is managing/maintaining.